# How do you call a 3rd party API from inside watson assistant?

Tags: python-3.x, ibm-watson, watson-assistant

Creating a chatbot using IBM's Watson Assistant, and I need to make a determination I'm trying to send the zip code to a third party API that will return the city and state so I know where the client is located so I can (a) know which services are available and (b) have a better idea on how to direct the conversation from there.  But I am at a loss as to how to do this.

I can do this from within Python, but trying to code it in a JSON editor doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

Webhooks are used to do this from inside the Dialog skill in an Assistant.

[IBM Watson Assistant webhooks documentation](https://cloud.ibm.com/docs/assistant?topic=assistant-dialog-webhooks)

The docs do not mention it, but the Assistant will POST to the URL with a JSON body containing the parameters you specify as key value pairs. For example if in the Dialog Node the context variable $zipcode equals '99501' and you specify the parameters "key" = `zipcode` and "value" = `"$zipcode"`.

Then the HTTP post body is

```
{ "zipcode" : "99501" }
```

The response from the service is put into another context variable, and this can then be used for other things. For example in the Dialog Node which calls the webhook, in the "Return variable" section put `webhook_result_zipcode` to put the response into that context variable.

You can also in the dialog node Assistant responds section, return a message which contains some part of the webhook response. For example in the Dialog Node editor
"If assistant recognizes" `$webhook_result_zipcode` "Respond with" `The code is "$webhook_result_zipcode.response.result.sent"` This will tell the user the code which is returned deep within the webhook response in `response.result.sent` in the response body.

You can also click the Cog next to the response, and in the dialog, click ... next to "Assistant responds" and open the context editor. This opens a context editor (at the top of the dialog) which allows setting of another context variable from part of the webhook response. For example under "Then set context" for "Variable" set `zipcode` and for "Value" set `"$webhook_result_zipcode.response.result.sent.zipcode"`. This will extract a zipcode value from deep within the webhook response and place it in the context variable `zipcode`.

Of course then you must find a zipcode location service which accepts a HTTP post and looks for the code in the body.